# Lua: Is there a way to concatenate "nil" values?

Tags: lua, concatenation, null

I have the following function in Lua:

```
function iffunc(k,str,str1)
  if k ~= 0 then
    return str .. k .. (str1 or "")
  end
end
```

This function allows me to check if value k is populated or not.  I'm actually using it to determine if I want to display something that has zero value.  My problem is this: I'm trying to concatenate a string of iffunc(), but since some of the values are 0, it returns an error of trying to concatenate a nil value.  For instance:

```
levellbon = iffunc(levellrep["BonusStr"],"@wStr@r{@x111","@r}") .. iffunc(levellrep["BonusInt"],"@wInt@r{@x111","@r}") .. iffunc(levellrep["BonusWis"],"@wWis@r{@x111","@r}")
```

If any of the table values are 0, it'll return the error.  I could easily put 'return 0' in the iffunc itself; however, I don't want a string of 000, either.  So how can I work it where no matter which values are nil, I won't get that error?  Ultimately, I'm going to do an iffunc on the levellbon variable to see if that's populated or not, but I've got that part figured out.  I just need to get past this little hurdle right now.  Thanks!

Comment: Cant you just return an empty string (`""`) when `k` is 0?

Comment: D'oh!  I can't believe it was that simple.  I blame it on the hour of coding and lack of sleep.  Thanks!  Just have to modify the function a bit now.

Comment: Just so you know in future, you can do this: `something and A or B`. If `something` evaluates to true it will push the value A, otherwise it will push the value B. Example: `k ~= 0 and str..k..(str1 or "") or ""`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You should definitely add that as a proper answer.

Comment: Selected answer works fine, however this also seems to be working fine for me : 

    print("this is a string " .. tostring(nilObject))


Above line prints  output : 

    this is a string nil

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
function iffunc(k,str,str1)
  if k == 0 then return "" end
  return str .. k .. (str1 or "")
end
```

Comment: Just a remark, if you **do** have a reason to concatenate a nil value, you can do: `'hi' .. string.char(0x00) .. 'there'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `else` statement in the function, where you return an empty string (`""`).